# how to import reports from google analytics?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

How can I import reports from google analytics to my application ?. Is there any API provided by google to get the reports ?

Comment: What kind of application are you referring to? Android?

Comment: @RaoulGeorge I am trying to use the report for a rails app.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Nearly all of the report data in Google Analytics is available in the [Google Analytics Data Export API](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/home.html).

There is full, comprehensive documentation on that site, as well as links to libraries.

From your past questions, it looks like you might be interested in a Ruby library for accessing the Google Analytics Data Export API. The documentation links to [garb](https://github.com/vigetlabs/garb) and [gattica](https://github.com/rumble/gattica).

Comment: Thanks :) . I will check the gems and GA Data Export API.

Answer (score 2):

Update:
Most of the gems are abandoned.
Check how to use the official Google API gem with Analytics here: https://gist.github.com/joost/5344705